# Tab widget have always in capital alphabets in android 4.0

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, tabwidget

[image]In Android 4.0 i put tab bar with two widget.
    in code i write in small alphabates(new) but in application it should always display (NEW)
         How to write small alphabates on tab in android 4.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default theme for tab views in Android 4.0 (the Holo theme) has `android:textAllCaps` set to true. You can create your own theme and then apply it to the action bar in your manifest to override this behavior. For more information on styling the ActionBar and creating your own styles, see:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html
and
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html

Answer (score 20):

Theres no need to create custom theme

In source code..

```
   TextView tv =  (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(index).findViewById(android.R.id.title); 
   tv.setAllCaps(false);
```

Comment: setAllCaps() is not available in android 2.x, this solution will not work there.

Comment: @Manohar Well, TABS are not available in android 2.x so this entire question is relevant only for Android 3+. In case you are using ActionBarSherlock or ActionBarCompat library the similar approach is applied there.