# Change Title Text Case to lowercase in Sherlock ActionBar Tab Views

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I created a tab application using Sherlock ActionBar Tab Views.  I like to change the Tab title to lowercase.  see screen shot

[image]

I want to change TAB1 to tab1

Any solution is greatly appreciated

my code as follow

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

// Declare Variables
ActionBar mActionBar;
ViewPager mPager;
Tab tab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from activity_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Activate Navigation Mode Tabs
    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Locate ViewPager in activity_main.xml
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    // Activate Fragment Manager
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // Capture ViewPager page swipes
    ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener ViewPagerListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            // Find the ViewPager Position
            mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    };

    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPagerListener);
    // Locate the adapter class called ViewPagerAdapter.java
    ViewPagerAdapter viewpageradapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(fm);
    // Set the View Pager Adapter into ViewPager
    mPager.setAdapter(viewpageradapter);

    // Capture tab button clicks
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // Pass the position on tab click to ViewPager
            mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };

    // Create first Tab
    tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1").setTabListener(tabListener);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

    // Create second Tab
    tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2").setTabListener(tabListener);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

    // Create third Tab
    tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab3").setTabListener(tabListener);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

 }
```

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953240/tab-widget-have-always-in-capital-alphabets-in-android-4-0 See this link.

Answer (score 1):

Please add this in TabLayout tag of xml file

```
app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
```

this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

try this cod

```
text-transform: capitalize;
```

Comment: I not familiar with actionbar tab view.  Where to implement above code

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

> ```
>    tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1").setTabListener(tabListener);
>     mActionBar.addTab(tab);
>
>     TextView x1 = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
>               .findViewById(android.R.id.title);
>       x1.setAllCaps(false); 
>
>       // Create second Tab
>     tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2").setTabListener(tabListener);
>     mActionBar.addTab(tab);
>        TextView x2 = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
>               .findViewById(android.R.id.title);
>       x2.setAllCaps(false); 
>     // Create third Tab
>     tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab3").setTabListener(tabListener);
>     mActionBar.addTab(tab);
>  TextView x3 = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
>               .findViewById(android.R.id.title);
>       x3.setAllCaps(false);
> ```