# how To Set Name Of Tabs in Lowercase LIke I Want In android

Tags: android, tabs

I'm developing a screen with three fragments tabs. The tabs title only have their first letter in uppercase:

```
 private String[] tabs = { "About Me", "Education","ProfileEdit"};
```

But when I run the app, the titles are displayed all in uppercase.

How can I make the tabs display the words properly?

Tabs setup code:

```
  private String[] tabs = { "About Me", "Education","ProfileEdit"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editprofile);
    user=(UserModel)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("USER");
    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name.toLowerCase())
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
```

**UPDATE**

I edited the theme with textAllCaps false, but the words display the same way:

```
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyMenuTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyMenuTextAppearance</item>
</style>
<style name="MyMenuTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tab widget have always in capital alphabets in android 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953240/tab-widget-have-always-in-capital-alphabets-in-android-4-0)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11340762/1318946

Comment: @PedroOliveira ...Sir I was Unable To Reach About My Solution from DEVELOPER Guid

Comment: @ツFellinLovewithAndroidツ SIR I m using Actionbarsherlock theme

can you sugges me where to edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default theme for tab views in Android 4.0 (the Holo theme) has android:textAllCaps set to true. 
See:

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html

Comment: i m Using Actionbar sherlock Theme Can U Tell mE How to Set false

Comment: First Later Should BE  In Caps ..not All in small letter

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250105/how-to-change-actionbar-tab-textstyle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250105/how-to-change-actionbar-tab-textstyle) in this i Followed The Answer ..But My Tab Name All In Small Letter

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />
```